# Laravel 7 SPA API Authentication with Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, middleware

I've developed multiple traditional Laravel 5.x web apps with blade &  Vue components, but now I'm developing a new Laravel 7 SPA app with React and Sanctum and I have installed the UI/Auth package (which is now separate).

I can log in with my React/Axios form, but can't get the logged in user (with "Auth::user()")  in routes defined in "routes/api.php". But when I define a different route in "routes/web.php" that calls the **exact same** controller/method, I **DO** get the logged in user.

Maybe it has something to do with middleware definitions in "app/Http/Kernel.php" - I have:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since the post was made, and i am not aware if you have figured out the answer.

You might have forgotten to use the auth:sanctum middleware to be able to inject the current authenticated user.

Thats the only thing i can point to with what you have provided in terms of code.

Answer (score -1):

The default `api` middleware stack is stateless. I don't know what your `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` does here.

So there are a couple solutions to fix this:

#### Add the same middleware as `web`

Add some extra middleware to your `'api'` group so your cookies will identify your session (only the first one is mandatory), just as it works with the `'web'` middleware:

```php
StartSession::class,
AuthenticateSession::class,
ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

Note that this makes your API stateful (since it now receives a session), which might be undesirable.

#### Use the built-in `token` guard for authentication

This is defined as the default driver for the `api` auth guard (see `config/auth.php`)

(https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L45)

It checks for the existence of (in this order):

- An `?api_token=xxx` query parameter
- An `api_token` request body parameter
- An `Authorization: Bearer xxx` header
- A header named `PHP_AUTH_PW`

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php#L97 `Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::97` to see how this happens.

The `token` guard relies on an `api_token` column in your `users` table, which is checked against one of the items in the list above. See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#database-preparation for an example migration on how to add this column.

#### Create a custom Auth guard in a service provider `boot()` method

As described here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#closure-request-guards . For example, this one authenticates a user using an `X-Api-Key` header:

```php
Auth::viaRequest('custom-token', function ($request) {
    return User::where('token', $request->header('X-Api-Key')->first();
});
```

You can then assign the `'driver' => 'custom-token'` in your `config/auth.php` file.

---

Note that this all is dependent on the `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class`, which should always be defined in your `config/app.php['providers']` list. This is the basic service provider that makes sure that the `Auth::user()` functions etc. are available in your code.

So if you want to require authentication for particular routes, you'd have to add the `'auth'` middleware (which is a shorthand for `\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class` as seen in `app\Http\Kernel::$routeMiddleware`) to either your `'api'` middleware group for api-wide authentication, or to separate routes.

Comment: This answer does not consider the usage of `laravel/sanctum` at all